# Enterprise Windows Store Apps publishing and distribution, Need clarifications on license requirements?

Tags: .net, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, sideloading

It is understood, need to get license for publishing and distributing Windows Store Apps. But it is not clear how much it costs and procedure. Please clarify the following:

My app has a requirement to not to publish the app in store, but to distribute it internally. [Sideloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn832613.aspx) seems to be option.

1. But I'm confused  what are costs for doing so? **For sideloading, it
   is said we need to buy keys. how much it is?**
2. Do I have to pay for each device that uses this sideloaded app? Is
   there any other costs or related software/license requirements with
   it? [this blog](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/CostToEnableSideloadingOnAWindows8Device.aspx) says there is per month subscription fee for devices.
3. **Is there any other requirement other than sideloading keys like OS
   version or domain?** Should the devices have particular version of OS
   or anything (such Windows 8.1 premium is must)? [this says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657971.aspx) it
   devices should be in domain?
4. If submitted to windows store, is there a way to hide from public
   view and allow the app to downloaded for intended users who are
   using Windows 8.1? [Hide this app in the store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt148548.aspx) will not work
   as it has a limitation of not able to use with Windows 8.1.
5. Technet says app can be sideloaded to all users as an image. But in
   that option also users have run the powershell and type the command
   to install the app. Is there a way to make enduser's life easier by
   making the installation simple as double click?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: When downvoting, it would be great if you can point out reason such whether this is duplicate question or anything wrong in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Windows Enterprise Edition and your devices in the domain you don't need to have a keys for sideloading.  As I know it works on Professional Edition too, but the domain account is necessary condition.

You can create your own Enterprise Store to publish application inside you company, but I don't have this experience.  We use SCCM or InTune to deploy the applications